# tailwind gradient don't works in background body

Tags: html, css, background, tailwind-css

i"m trying to change my bg-color to a gradient, and isn't working, when i put the classes, the bg becomes white like if don't have any classes

```
` <body class="bg-gradient-to-b from-black via-black to-purple-900">
    <h1 class="bg-slate-500 cursor-pointer">Testing</h1>
  </body>
```

`

I Tried to change everything, i copy and paste code from internet and anything works.

Comment: Hello - have you imported the tailwind colors to your project? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-the-default-colors